# incrementing alphanumeric strings in php

Tags: php, auto-increment, increment, alphanumeric

```
$x = 'a'
$x ++;
```

Outputs b

```
$x = 'z'
$x ++;
```

Outputs aa

I'm trying to get this same result but using a charset array, so I could use numbers, and capital letters as well for a more possible combinations, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
   $str = 'a';
   echo ++$str; // b

   $str = 'z';
   echo ++$str; // aa

   $str = 'aA';
   echo ++$str; // aB
?>
```

Comment: that doesn't work. it may look like it works but it just capitalizes the last character of every output. http://puu.sh/4G6Pw.png